# When pronouncing latin taxonomy names is there a rule when the letter p is voiced?

Tags: pronunciation

Pterodactyl -- Is the p voiced?   tero- dactyl

Pteridology -- Is the p voiced?   teri- dology

Dyropteris (genus name) - Is the p voiced? Dryo- pteris

Comment: By "voiced" do you mean "pronounced out loud"? Voicing is a term for a specific kind of pronunciation.

Comment: Pronouncing "pterodactyl" without a "p" sound is actually something particular to English, not Latin! In French, the corresponding word starts with an audible /p/ sound (ptérodactyle), and the source language for words starting with these kinds of clusters, Ancient Greek, is thought to have likewise prononuced both consonants in words starting with these kinds of clusters. See the Linguistics post [Are syllable initial consonant clusters pronounced in Ancient Greek?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/21306) for some discussion.

Comment: There are also some English SE questions about the history of words starting like this: [History and Explanation of Scientific English Pronunciation Convention: PS, PN, PT](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359101), [Pterodactyl and Archeopteryx: Silent P vs Voiced P](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103014)